# Open an excel workbook after code executes

Tags: vba, excel

I know this has been asked before, but for the life of me I cannot get this simple code to work. I keep getting the compile error "User-defined type not defined" on `Dim wbopen As Workbook`
line. I know the workbook has to be open to define it, and the file path should be Z:\Manufacturing\02- Schedules\01- Buffer Prep
while the file name is the only .xls in the folder. Why is this happening? Also, this is executing in a Word file. Not sure if that matters. Thanks everyone!

```
Sub fileopen()

Dim wbopen As Workbook
Dim strFileName As String
Dim strFilePath As String

strFilePath = "Z:\Manufacturing\02- Schedules\01- Buffer Prep\"

strFileName = Dir(strFilePath & "*.xls")

Set wbopen = Workbook.Open(strFileName)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does matter that it is a Word Document.  You have to add a reference to Microsoft Excel Object Library.  From the top bar:
`Tools -> References ->` find `Microsoft Excel [version number] Object Library` and check it.

Comment: Oh...welp that's embarrassing! Thanks! 
Now I'm getting an "object required" error on line

    Set wbopen = Workbook.Open(strFileName)

Comment: Should be `Workbooks.open`.  I think you're missing the 's'

Comment: Oh man. Tiny mistakes. Thanks again. It went to the right location, and then told me it couldn't find the file BUT it told me the file name! Going to have to figure out what's going on now.